# Why ReactNative Dimensions component is reporting lowers resolutions?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, background

I'm programming an application with React Native (v0.45.1) and using my S6 as a testing device. I'd set a background image which matches exactly my cellphone resolution size but its looking huge on screen, enough to only show me a small chunk of my background image.

Just for debugging purposes I'd added this lines in my render method to get my device dimensions:

```
let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
console.warn(height, width);
```

and the output I got from those lines is: 360 x 640. How can that be possible? I'd taken a screenshot and shared to a coworker and the picture size is: 1440 x 2560, which is exactly my cellphone resolution.
A few days ago the same happened to me at work, for the record I was working with a tablet that time and not using my cellphone. Any ideas about what is happening or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions you get from `Dimensions` are in `dp` (for Android) and the picture size is in `px` (pixels).

Basically, you work in `dp` on your app and the actual pixels values will vary between devices depending on their pixel density. This means their pixels might be smaller/bigger, thus `dp` represents the real-world-uniform-pixel-size if you will.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was missing!, thank you very much mate.